# Как извлечь данные (сумма значений ключа) из списка словарей в python?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Получаю данный словарь в переменную `traffic_data`:

```py
traffic_data = {
    'status': 'ok',
    'status_msg': 'Server stat information',
    'data': [
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 01:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.2975588607222222,
                'disk_reads': 13594,
                'disk_writes': 632047,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 121909,
                'vnet_tx': 41186
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 02:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.8375333826666667,
                'disk_reads': 1842,
                'disk_writes': 937,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 111693,
                'vnet_tx': 82710
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 03:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.779645068138889,
                'disk_reads': 5,
                'disk_writes': 692,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 107762,
                'vnet_tx': 79722
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 04:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7070395834444443,
                'disk_reads': 26,
                'disk_writes': 343,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 95410,
                'vnet_tx': 57916
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 05:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7293514661944442,
                'disk_reads': 6,
                'disk_writes': 1244,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 230214,
                'vnet_tx': 170108
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 06:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7065734677222222,
                'disk_reads': 4,
                'disk_writes': 230,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 90813,
                'vnet_tx': 55879
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 07:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7247692301944444,
                'disk_reads': 100,
                'disk_writes': 906,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 138628,
                'vnet_tx': 106986
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 08:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.748234856861111,
                'disk_reads': 5,
                'disk_writes': 308,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 119781,
                'vnet_tx': 69886
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 09:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7465629244166665,
                'disk_reads': 3,
                'disk_writes': 842,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 161440,
                'vnet_tx': 117674
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 10:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7961740783333333,
                'disk_reads': 4,
                'disk_writes': 1012,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 172917,
                'vnet_tx': 133916
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 11:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7930849220277778,
                'disk_reads': 3,
                'disk_writes': 162,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 120323,
                'vnet_tx': 67566
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 12:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.7449925691944443,
                'disk_reads': 3,
                'disk_writes': 217,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 117347,
                'vnet_tx': 68107
            }
        },
        {
            'dt': '2022-03-16 13:00:00',
            'stat': {
                'cpu': 1.765499081388889,
                'disk_reads': 3,
                'disk_writes': 312,
                'lnet_rx': 0,
                'lnet_tx': 0,
                'vnet_rx': 115767,
                'vnet_tx': 69762
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Как получить сумму всех значений двух ключей, `vnet_rx` и `vnet_tx`? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А с чем у вас возникла проблема? Даже если попытка неудачная, покажите её, чтобы было от чего помогать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переберайте список через `for` и суммируйте значения по ключам

```py
traffic_data = {'status': 'ok', 'status_msg': 'Server stat information', 'data': [{'dt': '2022-03-16 01:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.2975588607222222, 'disk_reads': 13594, 'disk_writes': 632047, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 121909, 'vnet_tx': 41186}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 02:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.8375333826666667, 'disk_reads': 1842, 'disk_writes': 937, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 111693, 'vnet_tx': 82710}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 03:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.779645068138889, 'disk_reads': 5, 'disk_writes': 692, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 107762, 'vnet_tx': 79722}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 04:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7070395834444443, 'disk_reads': 26, 'disk_writes': 343, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 95410, 'vnet_tx': 57916}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 05:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7293514661944442, 'disk_reads': 6, 'disk_writes': 1244, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 230214, 'vnet_tx': 170108}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 06:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7065734677222222, 'disk_reads': 4, 'disk_writes': 230, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 90813, 'vnet_tx': 55879}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 07:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7247692301944444, 'disk_reads': 100, 'disk_writes': 906, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 138628, 'vnet_tx': 106986}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 08:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.748234856861111, 'disk_reads': 5, 'disk_writes': 308, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 119781, 'vnet_tx': 69886}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 09:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7465629244166665, 'disk_reads': 3, 'disk_writes': 842, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 161440, 'vnet_tx': 117674}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 10:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7961740783333333, 'disk_reads': 4, 'disk_writes': 1012, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 172917, 'vnet_tx': 133916}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 11:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7930849220277778, 'disk_reads': 3, 'disk_writes': 162, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 120323, 'vnet_tx': 67566}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 12:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.7449925691944443, 'disk_reads': 3, 'disk_writes': 217, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 117347, 'vnet_tx': 68107}}, {'dt': '2022-03-16 13:00:00', 'stat': {'cpu': 1.765499081388889, 'disk_reads': 3, 'disk_writes': 312, 'lnet_rx': 0, 'lnet_tx': 0, 'vnet_rx': 115767, 'vnet_tx': 69762}}]}
t = 0
r = 0
for i in traffic_data["data"]:
  t += i["stat"]["vnet_tx"]
  r += i["stat"]["vnet_rx"] 

print(f"vnet_tx = {t}\nvnet_rx = {r}")
```

Вывод

```py
vnet_tx = 1121418
vnet_rx = 1704004
```